# R: .N in data.table returning 0 columns

Tags: r

I have searched and can't find a similar question. I'm trying to count the rows in a data.frame in which the value of the `VAL` variable is equal to 24.

I downloaded the data from https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2Fss06hid.csv

and read it to R using `read.table`:

```
download.file(fileUrl, destfile = "./Housing_Data/Housingdata.csv", method = "curl")
DT <- read.table("./Housing_Data/Housingdata.csv", sep = ",", header = TRUE)
```

I tried

```
DT[, .N, by=VAL]
```

which returned:

> Error in `[.data.frame`(DT, , .N, by = VAL) : unused argument (by = VAL)

```
DT[, .N]
```

returns:

> data frame with 0 columns and 6496 rows

However, when I run `head(DT)` it returns as if the columns are loaded correctly.

I'm really not sure where I'm going wrong here, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please study the introductory stuff supplied at https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started.

Comment: @UweBlock thanks for this, I've just noticed your comment and had a look through, this is very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to use data.table operations on a data.frame. And your syntax looks a little off for the data.table as well.

This is how you would find the nrow where VAL == 24

```
nrow(DT[DT$VAL==24,])
```

If you want to do this with a data.table you'll first have to a data.table. Run this:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)
DT[,.(Count = .N),by = .(VAL)]
```

Comment: Thanks, that's solved it. I thought read.table read it as a data.table. Quick follow up before I close this - would DT(read.table("./Housing_Data/Housingdata.csv", sep = ",", header = TRUE)) read it into R as a data.table when I'm reading the data?

Comment: @ogriofac if you want to read it in as a data.table use fread(). That will do it for you.

Comment: @Kristodersen Ok, I'll try that. Thanks so much for the help! (I'm still a noob so sorry if this should have been obvious!)

Answer (score 0):

I am using iris data set in R as an example.

Say you want to retain only those records which have `Sepal.Length` as `5.1`

So you would have

```
nrow(iris[iris$Sepal.Length == 5.1, ])
```

or

```
dim(iris[iris$Sepal.Length == 5.1, ])[1]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I didn't specify that I'm trying to learn data.table commands, but I got a good answer.

Comment: @ogriofac Drj's answer is using base R data.frame syntax not `data.table` commands.

Comment: @UweBlock yup, I see that, but the point of the task is to use data.table commands (which I hadn't specified in the answer). Kristoffersen's answer covered it nicely though.

Comment: @ogriofac yes, i observed that in the other solution. Just curious as to why you would want to restrict to `data.table`. The beauty of these languages is that you can solve a problem many ways and the solutions more often than not are not package / module specific. Anyways, I am glad that you got the answer you were looking for.

Comment: @Uwe, ah, I see where you're coming from. The main reason is that I'm still learning and had just covered data.table commands so wanted to practise it. Also I needed to manipulate a variable by subsetting and transforming, and this is really easy to do in data.table using the := command to create a new column. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the full URL looks like, but here is one option for you.

```
df <- read.csv("http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1516/E0.csv", 
               header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)[1:6]
```

Here is another way to do it.

```
library(dplyr)
MyData2 <- read.csv(file="http://www.grex.org/~ev/breweries_geocode.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realised I never concluded this by posting the solution. Kristofersen correctly pointed out that I was attempting to use a `data.table` command on a `data.frame`. The simple solution he suggested was to convert it:

```
library(data.table)
SetDT(DT)
DT[, .N, by=VAL]
```

The other option also works - using `fread` to load the data as a `data.table` in the first place. This is probably preferable, as it's more scalable.

Drj also provided a good answer allowing me to perform the same operation with `data.frame` commands, however I neglected to specify that I'm using `data.table` as I need to be able to create new columns a lot in this project, and `data.table` makes that really easy using the `:=` argument.

Thanks all for the answers.